# Regular Expression how to repeat a captured group?

Tags: c#, regex, regex-group

Having the following strings:

- AAA.BBBBBBBB et CCCCCC DDDDDDD 31.03.2012.xlsx
- AAA.BBBBBBBB ZZZZ et CCCCCC UUUU DDDDDDD 15.02.2015.xlsx
- AAA.BBBBBBBB DDDD et CCCCCC 23 DDDDDDD 03.11.2017.xlsx

I want to split the string in three parts, for instance in the first sentence:

- AAA.BBBBBBBB et CCCCCC DDDDDDD
- 31.03.2012
- .xlsx

In the third sentence:

- AAA.BBBBBBBB DDDD et CCCCCC 23 DDDDDDD
- 03.11.2017
- .xlsx

For the first sentence I tried the following regular expression:

```
^((\w+[\.\s]){5})(\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4})(.+)$
```

If I change the 5 for +, it don't work.

```
^((\w+[\.\s]){+})(\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4})(.+)$
```

How can I achieve this?

PD: I'm testing in Sublime before do the real work from a C# app.

Comment: remove `{}` brackets use just `+` sign so `^((\w+[\.\s])+)(\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4})(.+)$`. BTW when you want to test your regexes I recommend you https://regex101.com/

Comment: You don't need a regex for that the 15 characters on the left are always going the be the same length

Comment: SublimeText 3 uses PCRE engine and C# uses .NET - that is only OK if your pattern is going to be basic.

Comment: What do you think will happen if you change the `{5}` to `{5,}`?

Comment: What @prospector said. You can get the file extension with lastIndexOf, the date is the 10 characters before that, and the name is the remaining part. Using regex will likely end up causing more problems then it solves. This is just basic sub-string manipulation.

Comment: @Erick, please accept a working answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use named groups along with this regex:
        `^(?<name>.*)(?<date>\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4})(?<file_ext>.+)$`

```
string input = 
@"AAA.BBBBBBBB et CCCCCC DDDDDDD 31.03.2012.xlsx
AAA.BBBBBBBB ZZZZ et CCCCCC UUUU DDDDDDD 15.02.2015.xlsx
AAA.BBBBBBBB DDDD et CCCCCC 23 DDDDDDD 03.11.2017.xlsx";

string pattern = @"^(?<name>.*)(?<date>\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4})(?<file_ext>.+)$";
foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(input, pattern, RegexOptions.Multiline))
{
    // for each line you can use:
    // match.Groups["name"] , match.Groups["date"] and match.Groups["file_ext"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the date will always be the same length you don't need a regex. I don't like using regex because they're slow.

You can put this in a loop, I tried it for each string you provided it works fine. Not the cleanest code I rushed it, but you get the idea.

```
string fileString = "AAA.BBBBBBBB ZZZZ et CCCCCC UUUU DDDDDDD 15.02.2015.xlsx";
string fileName = fileString.Substring(0, fileString.Length-15);
int findExtensionDot = fileString.LastIndexOf(".");
string fileExtension = fileString.Substring(findExtensionDot, fileString.Length - findExtensionDot);
string getDate = fileString.Substring(fileName.Length, fileString.Length - findExtensionDot + 5);

Console.WriteLine(fileName);
Console.WriteLine(fileExtension);
Console.WriteLine(getDate);
```

Here are the results:

```
fileName: AAA.BBBBBBBB ZZZZ et CCCCCC UUUU DDDDDDD 
fileExtension: .xlsx
getDate: 15.02.2015
```